# PostgreSQL SELECT only values inside jsonb data

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-9.6

I have a postgresql data with values (it is jsonb type column):

`SELECT data FROM orders;`

```
   [
    {
        "food_id": "1",
        "table": "A12",
    },
    {
        "food_id": "2",
        "table": "A14",
    }
   ]
```

I can easily SELECT by providing data as it is, but how to convert it into simplified ?

My expected result:

`SELECT ??? as food_tables FROM orders;`

```
["A12", "A14"]
```

I personally still did not understand how `jsonb_array_elements()` works.

Thanks!

Comment: "*I have a postgresql data with values*" - multiple values (rows)? Or just one?

Comment: "*I personally still did not understand how `jsonb_array_elements()` works.*" - it seems you already know the right approach. Can you be more specific about what you didn't understand, and show us how you tried to use it?

Comment: @Bergi multiple. I just dont know how to write syntax for the SELECT

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could perform a lateral cross join with the unnested array elements and extract the attributes:

```
SELECT jsonb_agg(d.elem -> 'table')
FROM orders
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(orders.data) AS d(elem)
GROUP BY orders.id;
```

Use `array_agg` instead of `jsonb_agg` if you want a PostgreSQL array.

It is a mistake to model tabular data as a JSON array. Change your data model so that each array element becomes a row in a database table.

Comment: Hi Laurenz, thanks for the answer. I cannot update the current data model since it is an existing old app. 

I tried your query but that is not what I needed. I needed the A12 and A14 in the same row. I've updated the question into "expected result".

Comment: Hi Laurenz, I see you updated your answer. Its almost correct! Unfortunately it also merges all other rows from same table into single row. @a_horse_with_no_name answer is the one.

Comment: You didn't specify what you want.

Comment: Thank you and sorry @Laurenz! I was okay to upgrade to pg12 but after seeing your updated answer, I can stay with pg9.6. Also great help with @a_horse_with_no_name.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Postgres 12 or later, you can use `jsonb_path_query_array()`

```
select jsonb_path_query_array(data, '$[*].table') as food_tables
from orders
```

Comment: Sorry I did not specify my PostgreSQL version. Mine is using 9.6

Comment: @mokalovesoulmate: then you will need to use Laurenz's answer